# The Internet works fine until Ubuntu wants to perform an update!

Tags: networking, apt, updates, internet, repository

I'm able to connect to the Internet (I'm typing this message on the same machine) but Ubuntu won't connect to my net connection when trying to update the OS and software, both via the GUI and via the terminal. Ubuntu version 22.10, connected via Ethernet (working) and it's not behind a firewall.

Via the terminal, when I type `sudo apt update` I get:

```
(base) anthony@Shodan:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for anthony: 
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local  InRelease [1,575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local  InRelease [1,575 B]
Ign:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease           
Ign:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease            
Ign:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease          
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease             
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Hit:10 https://download.cudo.org/repo/apt stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Pinging (`ping google.com`) works fine.

The OS side of Ubuntu isn't my forte. I would appreciate some assistance. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're running 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu). This release is [unsupported and has been unsupported for some months](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). That means you *won't get any new updates!* Please upgrade to an supported release - it's probably a good idea to go for a LTS version, which at this point in time would be 23.04.

Comment: Ok, perfect. That makes sense. Is there is one-click wonder button that will update my OS? sudo apt upgrade kicks out the same errors.

Comment: 23.04 is not LTS but agree otherwise.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the correction! I don't run Ubuntu myself, so keeping up with what's LTS and not... ;)

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to next release, you have to run `sudo do-release-upgrade`

If you have to add latest patched/updates to your current release (do-release-upgrade might require this) take a look at this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Update_sources.list

Comment: I am afraid this does not work. I get::

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Thanks for the link to that page. In short, this is insane. If your OS is too old, short of spending a lot of time (along with needing the expertise) messing with the OS, it's easier to wipe and reinstall.

Comment: Then read and implement what is described in the article I linked to .. that will allow you to apply the required updates.

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of that.